# Selected exporter does not support Font used in this report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, adobe, arabic, export-to-pdf

I am exporting a report to PDF in visual studio 2010. But when I use "Adobe Arabic" as font, an internal exception is thrown: "Selected exporter does not support one of the features used in this report". How can I resolve this problem without changing font in my report?

Comment: It works with other fonts, correct?

Comment: See: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3832639

Comment: Yes, note that I added this font lately

Comment: Concerning the documentation they suggested to change font, but I don't want to change it, plus it is not exporting to word document. I believe that I am missing a configuration somewhere in my crystal report to accept exportation with the new font, because any word doc with adobe arabic can be converted to pdf succefully. Any idea?

Comment: In that link folks talk about a MS security update that hindered CR's ability to export a large set of fonts. I recommend reading that entire page and following its links within to see if anything sounds like the exact issue you're facing. I found that page by Googling your error message. It sounds like many people have this issue, which has not yet been solved. Figuring out the miscommunication between CR and MS Office might not be possible, so I wouldn't advise putting the time to it. There are many similar fonts to Adobe Arabic, could they not work? I certainly appreciate having a favorite.

Comment: I tried simplify arabic and it is working fine. I will recheck this link, I hope to get a result, thank you